# how to remote desktop in amazon aws Ubuntu Server Cloud Guest 11.10 (Ocelot)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, desktop, remote

How can I connect remotely desktop or Gui to an Ubuntu Server Cloud Guest 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) server in Amazon AWS from a Windows Seven machine?

Can some one give me a link to a complete tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed these instructions when it was my first time around:

http://aws-musings.com/4-easy-steps-to-enable-remote-desktop-on-your-ubuntu-ec2-instance/

worked well, although now you might want to actually install the official nxserver which is limited to 2 simultaneous connections but if you're using it for remote desktop for yourself, then that's not a problem and you it does work a bit better-

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1840679